# .First() timing out while .ToList() works fine

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm having a weird issue with ".First()"-ing an IQueryable:

```
var tests = dbSet
                .Where(p => productIds.Contains(p.ProductID.ToString()) || p.ProductGroups.Any(pg => pg.GroupedID == groupedId))
                .Select(p => p.Tests.Where(t => t.StatusID == 1 && t.TestType == 1));

            var testList = tests.ToList();
            var testFirst = tests.FirstOrDefault();
```

The .ToList() runs fine and in less than a second, but the .First() is seemingly really slow and eventually times out. I can obviously get round this problem by doing tests.ToList().FirstOrDefault() but I thought that would be slower?

Also, if I change the initial query to something simpler:

```
var tests = dbSet
                .Where(p => productIds.Contains(p.ProductID.ToString()))
                .Select(p => p.Tests.Where(t => t.StatusID == 1 && t.TestType == 1));
```

The .First() works fine? So it's something to do with the extra or in that .Where() combined with the .First().

If anyone could explain what's happening here that would be great!

Comment: is this entity framework?

Comment: If this is entity framework or Linq2Sql, please turn on logging and look at the SQL's that are executed for the two statements.

Comment: Are you sure that the results are correct? Using `Contains` and `ToString()` looks very suspicious for server side queries. Instead of `Contains(x)` better use `Any(y => x == y)` and instead of `ToString()`, have a list of the same type as your `ProductID` available.

Comment: This seems to be almost certainly a matter of the database rather than the query. Logging the SQL produced and trying to run it directly would hence be informative. I'd guess that it's likely something that could be resolved with better indexing (quite possibly there being no indices at all yet?)

Comment: Yes it's entity framework, sorry. And yep, results are coming back fine (I know the Contains(p.ProductID.ToString() bit isn't the most efficient, but that part works fine on it's own).

Comment: Is .ToList().FirstOrDefault() *actually* faster, or does it also behave like .FirstOrDefault() does?

Comment: I'm just using .ToList().FirstOrDefault() right now and it works fine.

Comment: Are you able to do as others have suggested; i.e. use SQL Profiler to see what SQL is being executed for the 2 cases?